# Celery task state does not update

Tags: heroku, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I'm seeing a bizarre problem with a Django app which uses Celery as as the task queue:

1. I kick off a task.
2. During execution, the task calls update_state(...) to set the task state to indicate progress.
3. The task completes. I verify this through logs.

However, this view (http://myapp/tasks/37d9a3ac-5bd2-4791-9729-2234ff3be762/status) returns a STALE result for a variable amount of time well after the task has completed. I can repro this using both Redis and database as the back-end. *Eventually* the task state is returned correctly, but this really breaks my app because the UI polls to see if the task is completed before the user can do anything.

**EDIT: my app is deployed on Heroku. I wonder if Cedar does any response caching??**

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this was not related to Celery. It was happening because my AJAX query to task/{id}/status was getting cached by the browser. Telling jQuery to not cache the response did the trick!